# How to make two simultaneously running infinite loops in C?

Tags: c, multithreading

It is necessary that the two cycles work simultaneously and at the same time be infinite. I previously did this in Java and Python, but when I tried to do this in C I encountered a problem.

If I do this in Java:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // some code
            }
        }
    }).start();

    while (true)
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Or in Python:

```python
def thread():
    while True:
        # some code

def main():
    t = threading.Thread(target = thread)
    t.start()

    while True:
        # some code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

All ok, but when I do this in C:

```c
void *thread(void *args)
{
    while (1)
    {
        // some code
    }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

    while (1)
    {
        // some code
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Only the loop in the thread runs and the compiler simply does not read the code after creating the thread.. So how to do this?

Comment: Do you know what `pthread_join` does?

Comment: pthread_join will never resume because your original thread will never terminate

Comment: "... and the compiler simply does not read the code after creating the thread" - Now that's a twist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `pthread_join` function tells the calling thread to wait until the given thread finishes.  Since the thread you start never ends, `main` waits forever.

Get rid of that function to allow the main thread to continue after starting the child thread.

```
int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread);

    while (1)
    {
        // some code
    }

    return 0;
}
```